# Загрузка данных на сервер при появлении подключения к интернет

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

Друзья. Есть php скрипт на локалхосте. Этот скрипт заполняет локальную базу какими то данными. И есть точно такой же скрипт на удаленном сервере т е в интернете. Пользователь по умолчанию заполняет локальную базу данных (так как в некоторых местах могут быть проблемы с подключением к интернету) а при появлении подключения вся заполненная информация с локалхоста должна автоматически (может и не автоматом а по нажатии на какую ни будь кнопку т е по требованию пользователя) отправляться на удаленный сервер и там уже заполнять существующую базу. Как можно сделать такую работу ? у кого какие идеи, мысли. Прошу сильно не ругать если вопрос звучит странным. ) спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно запилить API на сервере в интернете. Программа на рабочей станции (php-скрипт например) ждёт подключения к серверу, и спрашивает у API версию документа (базы данных). Дальше данные синхронизируются через тот же API.

Важно помнить, что обновления данных на сервере скорее всего должны быть авторизованными (будет печально, если кто-то потрёт мои данные). И что с данными можно работать не с одного устройства (я поменял базу на рабочем компе, а потом решил внести правки с домашнего), поэтому и нужна версия и синхронизация в обе стороны (но это не точно и зависит от задачи).